# Cant Load Package packagename Error

Tags: delphi

I am using Delphi 5. I am trying to install a package but while installing i am getting error "Can't load package packageName. The specified procedure could not be found".

What it means.
Please provide me solution to this error.

Thanks in advance

Regards,
Naren

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I've gotten messages like yours (but with specific procedure and package names included). This, in my case, was due to the fact that there was a version mismatch between the package I was installing and the package it was referring to that was already installed.

In other words, I already had a package on my machine but it was a *different version* than the one that the new package had been built against. The solution: make sure you've got the same (latest...) versions of both packages.  I hope this helps.